# Pole target prevent IK restraints

Tags: constraints, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to rig a character and I encountered a rather annoying problem:

I followed tutorials to create IK and pole targets etc

And it work fine, except: if I use pole target the IK constraints will not work (I mean the ones in the bone properties, not the one in constraints properties)

In simple steps:

- Create thigh > shin > foot + IK handle
- Add IK to shin, chain of 2, no pole target, ik handle setup
- lock Y and Z thigh rotations in bone properties
- moving IK handle will move the limb and respect the lock

BUT

- Create thigh > shin > foot + IK handle and Knee target
- Add IK to shin, chain of 2, knee target and IK handle setup
- lock Y and Z thigh rotations in bone properties
- moving IK handle will move the limb and not respect the locked rotation at all!

Here is a quick file I made to try this:
[image]

How do I make the IK restrains work with the target? Is it even needed? Is there a way to go around it if it is?
(I use Blender 2.83)
thanks in advance!